# Getting Snakemake to work nicely with datetime-based filenames

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm working with a large dataset where each file (stored online) has a URL that looks something like

```py
import datetime

def fname(dt: datetime.datetime):
    return "dataset-" + dt.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".gz"

def url(dt: datetime.datetime):
    return "url.com/" + fname(dt)
```

In my `Snakefile` I have a list of datetimes that I want to work with. For each I need to download the corresponding file from the internet (using `wget` or similar).

```
rule download:
    output: # would like to specify `fname(dt)`
    shell: # would like to `wget -O url(dt)`
```

What's the right way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way is to create a metadata table with each row representing the file name and download URL, and use this to query the download URL in `rule download` according to the file name

Or you can specify all files in `rule all`:

```
rule all:
    input:
        [fname(dt) for dt in dts]
```

Then `rule download`:

```
rule download:
    output: "{file}"
    shell: "wget -O url.com/{output}"
```

Comment: If I were going to create a metadata table like this (let's say a Pandas DataFrame with columns datetime, url, and local_fname), what would that download rule look like?

Comment: In that way I usually create a parameter directive to find the url, i.e., `url=lambda wildcards: downloads.loc[downloads.local_fname==wildcards.file, "url"]`. Then you can use this url in shell like `wget -O {params.url}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's close to what I ended up doing